Join results of a BYROW function that expands into multiple rows
I have two sheets, one containing user-entered data, and a second containing a bunch of data. I have included example sheets at the bottom of this question.
I'm trying to build a formula that for each row in the user-entered sheet would return 1 or more rows. I have a formula that works when only one row exists in the user-entered sheet but stops working as soon as there are multiple, because I'm using BYROW which expands into multiple rows.
I know I can use ={ range1; range2 } syntax to join ranges, but I'm unsure how to do that with what I have.
The formula in question:
=BYROW(
  IFERROR(
    FILTER(
      UserData!$B$3:$D$19,
      NOT(ISBLANK(UserData!$B$3:$B$19))
    )
  ),
  LAMBDA(
    row,
    FILTER(
      DataSheet!$D$2:$G,
      DataSheet!$A$2:$A = INDEX(row, 1, 1),
      (ISBLANK(DataSheet!$B$2:$B))+(DataSheet!$B$2:$B = INDEX(row, 1, 2)),
      INDEX(row, 1, 3) >= DataSheet!$C$2:$C
    )
  )
)

What is the solution to this? The order of the data returned by the formula is important.

User entered data:



B
C
D




Category1
Cat1Subcat5
3


Category4
Cat4Subcat3
2



Data reference sheet:



Categories
Subcategories
Value
Name
Source
?
Description




Category1

1
Cat1Item1
src

Description for Cat1Item1


Category1

2
Cat1Item2
src

Description for Cat1Item2


Category1
Cat1Subcat1
3
Subcat1Item1
src

Description for Subcat1Item1


Category1
Cat1Subcat2
3
Subcat2Item1
src

Description for Subcat2Item1


Category1
Cat1Subcat3
3
Subcat3Item1
src

Description for Subcat3Item1


Category1
Cat1Subcat4
3
Subcat4Item1
src

Description for Subcat4Item1


Category1
Cat1Subcat5
3
Subcat5Item1
src

Description for Subcat5Item1


Category4

1
Cat4Item1
src

Description for Cat4Item1


Category4

2
Cat4Item2
src

Description for Cat4Item2


Category4
Cat4Subcat3
3
Cat4Subcat3Item1
src

Description for Cat4Subcat3Item1




An example desired result from the formula would be:



Name
Source
?
Description




Item1
src

Description for item1


Item2
src

Description for item2


Subcat5Item1
src

Description for Subcat5Item1


Cat4Item1
src

Description for Cat4Item1


Cat4Item2
src

Description for Cat4Item2




what does 1-X rows mean?

@Blindspots An indeterminate amount of rows. At least 1 but the maximum depends on the data.


Can you [edit] to add an example of what you expect in the results, so we better understand the problem?   2. Your first example table, presumably UserData, is missing column D  but it is referenced in the LAMBDA:  INDEX(row,1,3). 3.  Is the range depicted in your second example table DataSheet!A1:G6?


@Blindspots 1. I can provide an example when I get home later. 2. That's just a poor explanation on my part. Assume the first table is the first few rows of UserData!$B$3:$D$19.

This is still difficult to understand.  1. Label your example tables with the same names as the sheets in your formulas (eg. DataSheet and UserData). 2. Only include data in your desired results table that can be derived from the DataSheet and UserDataexample tables. Item1? Item2?  3. Include column letters and row numbers for all your table to reduce confusion.

Given that the "order of the data returned by the formula is important", what is the desired sort order for the results?  How is that communicated in the question and the example desired results?

If my answer didn't solve your problem, consider reviewing the comments and adding any additional details that can assist us in better understanding what you need.

I ultimately came to the conclusion that a custom function in an App Script would be the easiest way to accomplish this.
/**
 * @param userData
 * @param reference
 * @customfunction
 */
function COLLATE_DATA(userData, reference) {
  userData = userData.filter(row => row[0] !== '')
  reference = reference.filter(row => row[0] !== '')
  const items = []
  for (const userRow of userData) {
    items.push(...reference.filter(referenceRow =>
      referenceRow[0] === userRow[0] && [userRow[1], ''].includes(referenceRow[1]) && userRow[2] >= referenceRow[2]
    ).map(row => row.slice(3))
  }
  return items.length === 0
    ? ''
    : items
}

Then within the spreadsheet, you can use the function as COLLATE_DATA(UserData!B3:D19, DataReference!A2:G).

Formuala
=LET(
   userRng, UserData!B3:D, refRng, DataSheet!A1:G,
   user, QUERY(userRng, "WHERE B <> ''"),
   colB, INDEX(user,,1), colC, INDEX(user,,2), colD, INDEX(user,,3),
   arr, MAP(colB, colC, colD, LAMBDA(b, c, d, TOROW(
     FILTER(ROW(refRng), INDEX(refRng,,1)=b, (INDEX(refRng,,2)="")+
       (INDEX(refRng,,2)=c), INDEX(refRng,,3)>=d)))),
   CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(refRng,TOROW(arr,1)),4,5,6,7))


LET's final argument, CHOOSECOLS, can be nested within a SORT function.

Explanation

user stores userRng after removing blank rows.
colB, colC, and colD each store one of the columns from user
arr stores the result of a MAP function:

All the rows in colB, colC, and colD are passed into a LAMBDA function row by row, where the current row of each column is stored in b, c, and d, respectively.
The LAMBDA's formula uses FILTER to return the row numbers in RefRng that match the criteria, and TOROW is used to transform multiple results into a single row.
Once the last row of values has been mapped into, and processed by, the LAMBDA, the result in arr is a 3D array of row numbers.


The next step is to convert the 3D array of row numbers, arr, to a single row without blanks using TOROW with the ignore_blanks option, 1.
That result becomes the rows argument for a CHOOSEROWS function applied to refRange
CHOOSECOLS is used to both define the order of the columns in the result, as well as discard any columns that are not specified.

Variation
=LET(
  userRng, UserData!B3:D, refRng, DataSheet!A1:G,
  user, QUERY(userRng, "WHERE B <> ''"),
  colB, INDEX(user,,1), colC, INDEX(user,,2), colD, INDEX(user,,3),
  arr, MAP(colB, colC, colD, LAMBDA(b, c, d, 
    TOROW(QUERY(refRng, "SELECT D, E, F, G WHERE A = '"& b
      &"' AND (B IS NULL OR B = '"& c &"') AND C >= "& d,0)))),
  QUERY(WRAPROWS(TOROW(arr),4), "WHERE Col1 <> ''"))


The final QUERY can include an 'ORDER BY' argument, or alternatively can be nested within a SORT function.

Explanation

Similar to the previous formula but QUERY is used instead of FILTER in the LAMBDA and returns the correct rows with the columns in the correct order with any removed as necessary.
The final step involves converting the 3D array arr to a row, then using WRAPROWS to restore the row to a 4-column 3D array.
This is done inside a QUERY function allowing any blank rows to be removed.

Functions
CHOOSECOLS  CHOOSEROWS  FILTER  INDEX  LAMBDA  LET  MAP  QUERY  ROW  TOROW  WRAPROWS

I just had to find a solution for myself, and looked up afterwards here...
My proposal :
= SPLIT(TOCOL( (Flattening and unpacking lines built further down)
BYROW(
  IFERROR(
    FILTER(
      UserData!$B$3:$D$19,
      NOT(ISBLANK(UserData!$B$3:$B$19))
    )
  ),
  LAMBDA(
    row,

TRANSPOSE(BYROW( (Hide each sub-line, packed by JOIN, into a column, in order to trick BYROW)
    FILTER(
      DataSheet!$D$2:$G,
      DataSheet!$A$2:$A = INDEX(row, 1, 1),
      (ISBLANK(DataSheet!$B$2:$B))+(DataSheet!$B$2:$B = INDEX(row, 1, 2)),
      INDEX(row, 1, 3) >= DataSheet!$C$2:$C
    )

; LAMBDA(r; IF(OR(ISBLANK(r)); ; JOIN("$EP"; r)))))
  )
)

; 3) (TOCOL will ignore errors and blanks => somewhat implementation dependent)
"$EP"; FALSE) (Parameters of SPLIT for unpacking columns)
Hoping my "inline" answer is clear enough and will help others.
PS: recreated from a similar case, there might be a typo here or there... you should get the idea.
